# Can't make Signals and Slots works in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to learn C++ using Qt for some basic visual applications. I want to make something simple at start, when I push a button, I want to display a text message somewhere. Here is my code:

main.h

```
#ifndef MYAPP_H
#define MYAPP_H

#include <QWidget>

class QLabel;
class QString;

class MyApp : public QWidget{
    public:
        MyApp(QWidget *parent = 0);
    protected slots:
        void showIt();
    private:
        QString *text_msg;
        QLabel *message;
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFont>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QString>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "main.h"

#include <fstream>

using std::map;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::ofstream;



/* implementation */
MyApp::MyApp(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){

    QString text_msg;
    text_msg = "This is my first message written in C++! \n It was printed with Qt!";

    setFixedSize(400, 280);

    QPushButton *quit = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"), this);
    quit->setGeometry(62, 40, 75, 50);
    quit->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));

    QPushButton *show_msg = new QPushButton(tr("Show!"), this);
    show_msg->setGeometry(30,15,75,45);
    show_msg->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));


    //message = new QLabel();
    QLabel *message = new QLabel(this);
    //message->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);
    //message->setText(text_msg);
    //message->setText("asdf");

    connect(quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(show_msg, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(showIt()));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;


    layout->addWidget(message);
    layout->addWidget(show_msg);
    layout->addWidget(quit);


    setLayout(layout);

        ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
}

void MyApp::showIt(){   
    //*text_msg = "xyz";
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example");
    myfile << "12121212121.\n";
    myfile.close();
    message->setText("1234");
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* assign messages for output 
    bool result;
    string key = "first", message="this is a sample text";
    result = Messages::add_message(key, message);
    */
    /* end */
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyApp my_simple_app;
    my_simple_app.show();
    return app.exec();

}
```

I don't understand why the program doesn't run the slot member function. I put there a some code that should print in a file some text to know if the code inside that function will be executed and the problem is at the QLabel message, but the member function are not executed.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 things that I needed to change to your code to make it work:

Firstly, in main.h you need to use the Q_OBJECT macro:

```
class MyApp : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
```

Secondly, in main.cxx, you need to change the connect call to the correct receiver (`this` instead of `myApp`):

```
connect(show_msg, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showIt()));
```

Thirdly, in main.cxx, you need to uncomment the code that creates the `message` label as a class member:

```
message = new QLabel(this);
```

Comment: I believe connect can be used with 3 arguments, making the `this` receiver implicit.

Comment: @Cubic Yes, that's true, but I wanted to make the fix more explicit, which will hopefully be more obvious to someone trying to learn C++ and Qt simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

The most important part is connecting the signal to the slot for a given object like this:

`connect(object_emitting, SIGNAL(clicked()),object_receiving, SLOT(showIt()));`

Answer (score 0):

`connect(show_msg, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(showIt()));` in this stainment change `qApp` to `this` and try again

that means

```
 connect(show_msg, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showIt()));
```

im not suer if there is different between `privat slots:` and `protected slots:` but usuely I use `privat slots:` also u can change it and try  :)